# $\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} ||f(x+h)-f(x)||_p=0$ for $p =\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For $f\in L^p(X)$ where $p\in [1,\infty)$. we have
$$\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} ||f(x+h)-f(x)||_p=0$$
I use the fact that continuous function with compact support is dense in $L^p$ to prove the case for $p<\infty$. If I consider the case $p=\infty$, the method that I used fails here, but how do I find an example that fails at $p=\infty$?

edit:

If I consider $f(x)=\chi_{[0,x]}$, then $||f(x+h)-f(x)||_\infty=1$, therefore
$$\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} ||f(x+h)-f(x)||_p= lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} 1 =1$$
Is this correct?

Comment: For example, consider the characteristic function of an interval.

Comment: @Rigel thank you. If I consider $f(x)=\chi_{[0,x]}$, then the norm still go to $0$. How do I construct it?

Comment: @Reinherd Why do you think that the norm goes to zero?

Comment: @saz I think I might be wrong about taking the limit directly to make $h=0$. Actually , the norm is always 1 before taking the limit. So it is still 1 even though I take the limit, is it?

Comment: Yes, the limit is $1$. (If you are unsure about this, you should take a look at the very definition of $\lim_{h \to 0}$.)

Comment: thanks for your advice.

Comment: Saying $f(x)=\chi_{[0,x]}$ doesn't make much sense - that would say that $f:\Bbb R\to L^\infty$, not $f\in L^\infty$. As already suggested, try $f$ equal to the characteristic function of _an_ interval. Like $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$.